How to disable session cookies completely in Flask-Security-Too when using token-based authentication?
I'm working on a Flask application using Flask-Security-Too for user authentication. I've enabled token-based authentication by passing tokens in the request headers, and I don't want the application to create or store session cookies for users. However, even with token-based authentication, Flask-Security is still creating and managing session cookies.
Is there a way to fully disable cookie-based session management in Flask-Security, so that no session cookies are created or stored for users?
Here’s my current configuration:
app.config['SECURITY_TOKEN_MAX_AGE'] = 3600  # Token expiration time in seconds
app.config['SECURITY_TOKEN_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED'] = True  # Enable token authentication
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY", '****************************')
app.config['SECURITY_CSRF_IGNORE_UNAUTH_ENDPOINTS'] = True
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE'] = False  # Disables session cookie over HTTPS
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY'] = False  # Allows JS to access the cookie
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE'] = 'Strict'  # Restricts cross-site access

Despite this setup, after session timeout, I receive the following message when trying to log in using my Angular application again: "You can only access this endpoint when not logged in."
Any help on how to prevent Flask-Security from creating session cookies would be appreciated.

seems like they're requiring the session cookie for the login.  After that it won't be used anymore.  It requires that to prevent a CSRF attack where an attacker forces the user to login using their (the attacker's) credentials.  It's then possible the victim inputs some information that the attacker can then recover from their own account.  See here (#1 tip): https://flask-security-too.readthedocs.io/en/stable/patterns.html#csrf-pro-tips
